# WSO2: No matching indices found

Tags: elasticsearch, wso2, kibana, analytics, wso2-api-manager

I'm using Elastic search to analyze my logs in WSO2 API Manager. I'm using basic authentication mode. After setting up Elastic and Kibana and configuring its setting, these errors appear when I want to see Kibana dashboards. How can I solve these problems?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Elasticsearch looks like there is no index which starts with `apim_event_faulty` or `apim_event*`, you can check all the indices in your Elasticsearch cluster by hitting `_cat/indices?v` API of Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thank you for your response. You're right. There is no index with these names. How can I solve this?

Comment: @nahidafzali kibana is just the UI on top of Elasticsearch , if index is not present than you can't create visualization on top of those indices, error message is very clear, you need to have these indices in you Elasticsearch, please upvote and accept answer as it provided answer to your query :)) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is `/repository/logs/apim_metrics.log` inside your WSO2 API Manager home directory.

- If you don't have the `apim_metrics.log` file, most like there is an issue in configurations you have done in API Manager. Refer this documentation https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/api-analytics/on-prem/elk-installation-guide/
- If you have the `apim_metrics.log` file, check the content. If it does not have any logs, most likely API Manger haven't gone through any event to trigger apim_event_faulty, apim_event_response logs. Try invoking an API and observe the logs.

Comment: There is an apim_metrics.log file. But, these two lines log is available: 11:27:23,821 [-] [Framework Event Dispatcher: Equinox Container: 292a4d39-1654-4749-9194-2f28a2711dce]  INFO ELKMetricReporter LogMetricReporter successfully initialized.

Comment: I invoked an API and some logs were saved in a file. But those errors come again.

Comment: Looks like you have WSO2 APIM configured just fine. Please check whether you have configured the ELK components correctly. Specially the Filebeat. Please check whether you have added the correct path to the apim_metrics.log file in your filebeat.yml file